# Building a CRUD Todo site with AXIOS and VUE

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, axios

I have a small app that I am working on to learn VUE and Axios. I am stuck on the update portion. I am trying to pass the ID to the form to update, but cannot grasp this at all. The delete is working as expected. The create auto loads as expected and task creation works perfect. I have watched several videos on how to actually implement the update using VUE, but just cannot get it. Tried to look up several videos and resorted to asking here. I am fairly new to coding, so if I am asking a noobish question, I appologize ahead of time.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <nav class="navbar col-12 navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Sam's Application
        </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div
      id="welcome-content"
      class="pb-5 pt-5 row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column"
    >
      <div
        class="col-4 p-4 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column"
      >
        <h1 class="text-success">Welcome to Sam's ToDo App!</h1>
        <p>
          This apps allows you to create tasks, delete, and make modifications.
          Come back later for more features. If you would like to see more,
          please send us a message!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="pt-5 w-75 row mx-auto pt-">
      <div class="col-4 align-items-center">
        <form class="p-4" id="form" @submit.prevent>
          <strong class="text-danger " v-if="edit"
            >Please make Changes and click Update</strong
          >
          <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-12">
              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="text"
                v-model="currentTask.name"
                v-if="edit"
              />

              <input
                class="form-control"
                type="text"
                v-model="form.name"
                placeholder="Task Title"
                v-else
              />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <input
                class="mt-4 form-control"
                type="text"
                v-model="currentTask.description"
                v-if="edit"
              /><input
                class="mt-4 form-control"
                type="text"
                v-model="form.description"
                placeholder="Task Description"
                v-else
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="mt-4 btn btn-warning"
            v-if="edit"
            @click="updateTasks()"
          >
            Update
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="mt-4 ml-3 btn btn-secondary"
            v-if="edit"
            @click="edit = false"
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            class="mt-4 btn btn-primary"
            v-else
            @click="createTasks"
          >
            Create New Task
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8 d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <table class="table table-striped ">
          <tr class="d-flex pl-5">
            <td class="col-4"><strong>Title</strong></td>
            <td class="col-4"><strong>Description</strong></td>
            <td class="col-1"></td>
            <td class="col-1"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="d-flex pl-5" :key="id" v-for="(tasks, id) of tasks">
            <td class="col-4" v-bind:key="tasks.id">
              {{ `${tasks.name}` }}
            </td>
            <td class="col-4">
              {{ `${tasks.description}` }}
            </td>
            <td class="col-1">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger"
                @click="deleteTasks(tasks.id)"
              >
                Delete
              </button>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="col-1">
              <button
                class="btn btn-warning"
                @click="
                  edit = true;
                  getCurrentTask(tasks.id);
                "
              >
                Edit
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      id: ``,
      tasks: [],
      form: {},
      name: "",
      description: "",
      route: "/api/tasks/",
      edit: false,
      currentTask: {},
    };
  },

  mounted: function() {
    this.getTasks();
  },
  methods: {
    getTasks() {
      axios
        .get(this.route)
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.tasks = [...data];
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
    getCurrentTask(id) {
      this.currentTask = id;
    },
    createTasks() {
      axios
        .post(this.route, this.form)

        .then(() => {
          this.getTasks();
          this.form = {};
        })

        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    deleteTasks(id) {
      axios
        .delete(this.route + id)

        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          this.getTasks();
          this.form = {};
        })

        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
    updateTasks(id) {
      axios
        .put(this.route + id, this.currentTask)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          this.getTasks();
        })

        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.container-fluid {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/64/26/fDOZxE.png);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
#form {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) !important;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

table {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

#welcome-content {
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I create same page on vue, thanks for help.

```html
<template>
  <div id="content">  
  <h1>...</h1>  
    <div>
      <label>Product Name</label> : <input type="text" id="txt1" v-model="model.productName"  />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Desciription</label> : <input type="text" id="txt2" v-model="model.descrption" />
    </div>
       
    <div>
      <button type="button" v-on:click="saveClick">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <hr />
  <h1>...</h1>
  <table border="1" style="margin:auto">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 100px">ID</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Product Name</th>
        <th style="width: 100px">Desciription</th>       
        <th style="width: 100px"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in model.list" v-bind:key="item.id">
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.productName }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.descrption }}</td>      
        <td><button type="button" v-on:click="deleteClick(item.id)">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "Product",
  data: function () {
    return {
      model: {
        productName: "",
        descrption: "",
        
      },
      list: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveClick() {      
      axios
        .post("http://example.com", this.model)
        .then((resp) => {
          this.getList();
          alert("success" + resp.data.id);
        });
    },
    getList() {
      axios.get("http://example.com").then((resp) => {
        this.model.list = resp.data;        
      });
    },
    deleteClick(id) {
      axios.delete("http://example.com" + id).then(() => {
         this.getList();
         alert("success");  
      });
    }
  },  
  mounted: function () {
    this.getList();
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You might want to check you template and script
 1. getCurrentTask() method only assigns the id. You might want to do this
 2. In template

    `<button class="btn btn-warning" @click="edit=true;getCurrentTask(task);">`

 3. In script getCurrentTask(task) method

    this.currentTask = task.id;
    this.form.name=task.name;
    this.form.description=task.description;

 4. I would suggest modelling of data also something like instead of using currentTask and form as different obejcts

   
{
      tasks: [],
      form: {name:"",description:"",id:""},
      route: "/api/tasks/",
      edit: false,
    }
```